# SimpleXML Lower level variable

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm parsing a file with simple_xml_load_file(), level by level. Here's the sample structure:

```
<person name="Joe Smith" ...>
   <info age="19">
     <height val="1.85" />
   </info>
   <info age="19">
     <weight val="82" />
   </info>
   <info age="19">
     <build val="14" />
   </info>
</person>
...
```

As I am parsing I am not going deep, as I don't need to. I do need the age however, without going through each info tag. I need the variables contained in `<person>` and only the age. How would I go about getting age without another loop?

```
$persons=$dom->person;
foreach($persons as $person){
   $name=$person['name'];
   $age=????
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
foreach($dom->person as $person){
   $name=$person['name'];
   foreach($person->info as $info) {
       echo $info['age'] . '<br>';
   }
}
```

Or if you want to get one age at a specific position:

```
echo $person->info[0]['age']; // Gets age attribute of first <info> node
```

Comment: any other way of doing it without another loop? there are tons of info tags and I am afraid it would slow the performance in case of a large file.